# Can the base dublivert object be hidden?

Tags: 3d-view, dupli-groups

Is it possible to hide (in the viewport) the base duplivert object, without also hiding all of its duplicates?

Comment: No, not currently possible unfortunately, I think its a known limitation of the current system. You can alternatively use a particle system instead, if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You have to give it a material with transparency. Set the Alpha to 0 and enable Transparency in Display settings, like this:
[image]

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is a workaround, and only really works well for Blender Internal/BGE, not Cycles